# What is a euphemism for enforcer?

Tags: euphemisms

As in a bad guy, thug, hatchet man, etc. who "persuades" people to pay. I'm trying to think of something overly professional and comedic.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is POB. I suppose professionals could be *debt collectors* or *bailiffs*. In SE UK we might speak of *the heavy mob* or *the heavies* for comedic effect, but I don't really see how "professional" and "comedic" could both apply to the same word.

Comment: When using something along the lines of "payment collection agent" to describe muscle, it's both professional sounding and comedic.

Comment: If he works for someone else, then Financial Planner, Accountant, CFO, Bookkeeper, Business Partner, Silent Partner. If he works for me, I would call him my Accounts Receivable Manager.

Comment: Got caught by the 5 minute rule for comment edits. If he is forcing me to pay, then I might tell people who really don't need to know that he is one of those above (except for accounts receivable manage). If he is my enforcer, I would call him my accounts receivable manager.

Answer (score 1):

Something like **Payment collection agent**?

- Payment collection agent
- Debt recovery officer
- Credit liaison manager

Perm any three from nine (or more...)

Comment: My sister is a payment collection agent.  Don't really think she is a bad guy or thug.   People may not like to take her calls but I don't think they would be afraid of her.

Comment: @RyeBread That's one of the reasons it can be a euphemism for a thug. Most such people aren't.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a bookie in college for 3 years.  Two common terms that were used to describe my position was **runner** or **collector**.  The less hostile clients called me a runner - I collected money and took bets from them.  The hostile clients would call me a collector and some of the older guys called me the bagman.

Answer (score 0):

Compliance agent. Attitude adjuster.

Comment: This answer could be improved by detailing why you believe these phrases would fit the desired meaning.

Answer (score 0):

## [Financial | Payment] Compliance [Professional | Officer]

Self explanitory.

or perhaps:

## Fixer

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixer):

> Fixer
> b: a person who adjusts matters or disputes by negotiation

Answer (score -2):

There's a few choices you could make here.

[Thug](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Thugs) would definitely work, though it lacks the 'overly professional' modifier you're looking for.

[Malefactor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malefactor) works if you want to get a general sense of crime-doing while sounding professional, though it lacks an explicit "extortion"-ness to it.

[Extortionist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extortionist) is all about getting people to pay through extortion.

[Mafioso](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mafioso) carries an especially 'sophisticated' feel to it, and gently masks the goonishness of the activity.

[Racketeer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/racketeer) sounds quite innocent unless you know what it actually means.

Though perhaps my favorite is [Highwayman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highwayman), which is an especially archaeic term one might use to describe themselves for 'a sense of romanticism', despite no highways being involved.

Comment: I would consider all of these *more* suggestive than "enforcer".

Comment: Hmm...you might be right.  I think I may be going in the wrong direction.